# IBM Watson Assistant: How to ensure check-out date is after check-in date

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am creating a hotel room booking chat bot using IBM Watson Assistant. How can I make sure (probably with conditions) that the check-out date entered by the client is after the check-in date they entered? Conditions in Watson Assistant can only compare a date relative to a user time and not to the input!
The image here [process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXwCZ.png) will show the process that I am working on.

Comment: Can you share more about the bot and what you do? You can store both dates in context variables and run checks on them. If you have a backend system to manage user data, you could also perform the check there and return an error condition. Many options...

Comment: Hi. So I am using Watson Assistant to create a hotel room booking chat bot. Once the user input the check-in date, we will ask for the check out date. Once the user input this check out date, we need to verify that it is not before or on the same day as the check in date. I have added an image down in the reply so that it shows what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please EDIT your question with all details and embed images, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use context variables or entities.

With context variables, save the dates into context variables. You can then compare the two date context variables, using any of the date comparison methods - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-date-time

```
<? $checkinDate.before($checkoutDate) ?>
```

If you use entities pulled out from the input, then this will be:

```
<? @checkinDate.before(@checkoutDate) ?>
```

You can also mix and match, say you have the checkinDate already (and its in the future) and you have stashed the value in context. Then your next utterance may ask for the checkout date, in which case your check becomes.

```
<? $checkinDate.before(@checkoutDate) ?>
```